# Ember js how to access query params in controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This is my router -

```
this.resource('lead');
```

And I am doing a transition to lead route like this -

```
var requestedCourseId = 102;
this.transitionTo('lead', {queryParams: {courseId: requestedCourseId}});
```

How do I access the `coureId` sent in queryParams in my `LeadController` ?

Answer (score 0):

First add 'queryParams: ['courseId']' to your controller,.
And you can call 'this.get('courseId')' in controller instance directly, its value is 102.

```
App.LeadController = Ember.Controller.extend({
      courseId: null,
      queryParams: ['courseId']
});
```

Comment: I am getting it as NULL. I think it is not getting set.
When I do console.log(this.get('queryParams')); I get the follwing - 
["courseId", _super: function, nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function…]